# Constraining random HEX # colour generator to a certain range of colours

Tags: python, css

This code gives a random hex colour value every time it is run...

How would I make it spit out say, only greens and blues? Or reds and oranges and yellows?

```
these = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']

fff = []
for z in xrange(6):
    fff.append(these[randint(0,15)])
ccc = ''.join(fff)

color = '#' + ccc
```

Comment: Describe an exact problem you need a solution for...

Comment: It really depends on your needs. It's probably wiser for you to have a small number of colors that you randomly choose from. If you really wanted to do this you could consider taking the color cube represented by RGB and then define arbitrary disjoint volumes to be "red" or "green" or whatever. From there, I don't think there's an easy way to pick a point randomly within that volume with uniform probability. One observation is that if your volume is a rectangular prism then it's easy to pick a random point, so splitting your volume into rectangular prisms might give you... something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to generate blues and greens turn the red light "off"

```
'#{:06x}'.format(random.randint(0, 0x00ffff))
```

If you want to generate reds, yellows and oranges turn the blue light off

```
'#{:06x}'.format(random.randint(0xff0000, 0xffff00))
```

I took the color ranges from [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this in a function that takes three-bit mask, then do a sort of bitwise & on the resulting {ccc} to pass through r, g or b, values.